# MYSQL order by and group by empty value

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am trying to solve my problem with little complicated showing data from my table.
My table structure is like this:

[image]

```
/* CREATE TABLE */
CREATE TABLE table_name(
id int(11),
section tinytext,
time tinytext,
text time
);

INSERT INTO table_name(id, section, time, text)
VALUES (1, 'A', '10:00:00', 'text 1');

INSERT INTO table_name(id, section, time, text)
VALUES (2, 'A', '12:00:00', 'text 2');

INSERT INTO table_name(id, section, time, text)
VALUES (3, 'B', '10:00:00', 'text 3');

INSERT INTO table_name(id, section, time, text)
VALUES (4, '', '15:00:00', 'text 4');

INSERT INTO table_name(id, section, time, text)
VALUES (5, 'B', '12:30:00', 'text 5' );

INSERT INTO table_name(id, section, time, text)
VALUES (6, '', '9:00:00', 'text 6');
```

I get results like this:

[image]

It groups empty section into one section :-(

Have you any idea how to reach what I need? I need to order my data by time, but when they have the same section group it and then follow with data with next time (also if the section is empty)

Comment: Hi! Can you post your query? And the table structures using CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO? And can you also post the query that you tried?

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**. But anyway, what you ask is a job for a presentation layer, not the DBMS.

Comment: Ordering is unclear. Imagine that there as a row with empty `section` and `11:00` in `time` column - where it must be placed? And the same when `time` is `12:15`...

Comment: *But when I used for example* The query is not correct synthactically. And if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled then the output is non-deterministic. *I get results like this* Thos result does not match the data and query text.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with `GROUP BY (CASE WHEN section IS NULL OR section='' THEN id ELSE section END)`